# Do VMs like LLVM or PARROT allow usage of the same library from multiple languages?

Tags: virtual-machine, llvm, parrot

Is it possible to use one framework written in one Parrot (LLVM) language in any other Parrot (LLVM) language? 
(Like usage of .NET Framework from any CLR language)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parrot and LLVM are two different things made by two different organizations.

Parrot is a VM, and LLVM is a VM that can also compile statically.

**Edit**

Assuming the comments to my answer are correct:

1. LLVM allows you to call other LLVM code and also external C like libraries.
2. Parrot allows you to call other Parrot code, but not external C like libraries.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_virtual_machines

Comment: I think Jox is asking about both Parrot and LLVM

Comment: aardvark is right, I think :)
Qustion is not about "cross-vm-platform" libraries, but about possibility to use library written in one language for ParrotVM in any other Parrot targeted language.
Same question stands for LLVM.

Comment: Is it impossible to call C function or being called from C function in Parrot?

Answer (score 1):

**LLVM**

Stands for low-level virtual machine. It uses low-level opcodes that easily map to native machine code.

- Languages: Fortran, C, C++
- Applications: Systems Programming, Compiler Development

**Parrot**:

This is a high-level virtual machine. Its opcodes are much higher level then those in most virtual machines. This allows Parrot to generate efficient native code for dynamic languages.

- Languages: Ruby, Perl, PHP
- Applications: server-side scripting